# How could I see the space $Y$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

In the picture below:
[image]

which is the lemma 2.1 of the paper of Arhangelk'skii, I cannot understand the part that he tried the space $Y$ is closed. Could somebody help me?

Comment: When saying "the paper" you should probably add a citation.

Comment: Recall, in part, [this past question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/222553/8348) asking about why sequential spaces are countably tight.

Comment: The paper in question is A.V. Arhangel'skii and R.Z. Buzyakova, _On linearly Lindelöf and strongly discretely Lindelöf spaces_, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 127, pp.2449-2458,  [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-08/S0002-9939-99-04783-8/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Suppose that $x\in\cl Y$; then there is a countable $A\subseteq Y$ such that $x\in\cl A$. For each $a\in A$ there is an $\alpha(a)<\tau$ such that $a\in F_\alpha(a)$. Let $\beta=\sup\{\alpha(a):a\in A\}$; then $\beta<\tau$, since the cofinality of $\tau$ is uncountable, and $A\subseteq F_\beta$, since the sets $F_\xi$ are nested. But then $x\in\cl A\subseteq\cl F_\beta=F\beta\subseteq Y$.